# OCaml and Opam: unbound module Core

Tags: ocaml, opam

I'm trying to get an OCaml environment set up, and I've followed the instructions from appendix A of the Real World OCaml beta. I set up opam, and installed a version of OCaml with the command

```
$ opam switch 4.01.0dev+trunk
```

which passed fine. I then did an

```
$ eval `opam config env`
```

to pull in the changes. I'm running the correct top level, as

```
$ which ocaml
```

outputs

```
/home/bryan/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/bin/ocaml
```

I installed the Core package from Jane street, with the command

```
$ opam install core
```

Both ocamlfind and opam search show that the package was installed correctly. However when I try to open it either from the repl or in a file, I get the error 'unbound module Core'. e.g.

```
$ ocaml
# open Core;;
Error: Unbound module Core
```

Is there something I'm missing here? Why can't OCaml find my installed module?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

So I jumped the gun a bit. I forgot to add some items to my ~/.ocamlinit file. Specifically I forgot to add

```
#use "topfind"
#camlp4o
#thread
#require "core.top"
#require "core.syntax"
```

as mentioned in Chapter 1. D'oh!

Comment: Manually adding lines to config files?  Isn't that a bit archaic?

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I was just a little frustrated at the amount of setup required to get started with Opam, utop and the Core library.

Comment: @kristianp it is a bit of slog. Not the worst I've had so far, but not super straightforward either.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I’ve put those lines in the `.ocamlinit`, and the error keeps raising. :-(

Comment: Indeed my problem is quite different: running `ocaml`, `open Core.Std;;` works fine, but inside a script, it cannot be compiled – raises `Unbound module Core`.

Comment: Let it go… finally I realise what’s wrong: I was trying to compile using `ocamlc`, when the right way is by using `corebuild`. Sorry for bothering.

Comment: Now in [the wiki](https://github.com/realworldocaml/book/wiki/Installation-Instructions), but still a useful answer.

Comment: Requiring to edit a textfile as part of an installation procedure to achieve something that apparently everybody wants seems archaic to me as well. Or is the Core library so exquisite and exceptional? I just installed ocaml and I have no clue what the five lines added to ~/.ocamlinit mean. After just being asked by a script "[2/4] Do you want to update your ~/.ocamlinit?", I wonder why these five lines are not added as part of some installation script.

Comment: Just comment as supplement to this answer, here's a [video](https://asciinema.org/a/36250) showing how to install OPAM on ubuntu 14.04 and run `open Core.Std;;` in utop. I tested as the video goes on my env also. I'm using Mac OSX 10.10.5.

Comment: "core.syntax" is deprecated as of 2022 use "ppx_jane" instead. Follow this (dev.realworldocaml.org/install.html) for more details

Answer (score 12):

Please follow the steps in the [**Real World OCaml** Wiki - Installation Instructions](https://github.com/realworldocaml/book/wiki/Installation-Instructions).

Under [Setting up and using utop](https://github.com/realworldocaml/book/wiki/Installation-Instructions#setting-up-and-using-utop), the instructions state that you should add:

```
#use "topfind";;
#thread;;
#camlp4o;;
#require "core.top";;
#require "core.syntax";;
```

to your `~/.ocamlinit` file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're building your code with dune and you think you have core [installed](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/install.html), you still need to declare your app's dependencies in the dune file.

```rkt
; bin/dune
 (executable
  (public_name app)
  (name main)
  (libraries app core))
```

Comment: In my case (Ocaml 5.1.1, opam 2.1.5, on Ubuntu 22.04) no need to create file ~/.ocamlinit. Just adding `core` into bin/dune file as above make `dune build` and `dune utop` complete successfully.